# How do I avoid making a "video game forced to be a board game"?

Tags: game-design, mechanics

My last playtest for the game, useful as it was, resulted in a player saying it feels like a board game, but the players have to run and update the normally-passive numbers manually.

I'm worried that the time-delayed effects, debuffs/buffs wearing off, additional information for each unit, resources being assigned passively, among others, are the traits of a video game closely resembling [Battle For Wesnoth](https://lh5.ggpht.com/p914VAOVKShy6EHqvOS8ZE2no2UuDkNYeFqhyFXJ5n-YFYkTO573XvMMTxQOo2QblVs=h900) or [Duelyst](http://tradingcardgames.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/combat32.jpg).

What are some common pitfalls and solutions to them when a board game feels like a video game that you have to basically "compile" every turn?

Comment: Is your first sentence supposed to say "feels like a video game"? Also, it seems like this might be a better question for this site if you focus more clearly on the specific issues in *your* game, rather than the broader set of possible common pitfalls across all game. The questions in the title and last paragraph invite broader answers, while your second paragraph begins to explain some of what you're doing - so maybe add a bit more detail there, and rephrase the questions a bit?

Comment: Particularly, if you could elaborate on what kind of game you are designing, it would help a great deal.

Comment: In general, when a question has "What are some common pitfalls and solutions" it's not a question that's appropriate for Stack Exchange.